# Beginner question - Encapsulation and "Proxy Classes"

Tags: c#, .net, encapsulation

While learning c#, I have picked up the implication from reading other people's code that it's good practice to separate certain classes from the program by use of a sort of "Proxy Class".  Namely those programs with private data.

For instance, say I have  database class that performs just about all of my database interactions.  It has both a "Send data" and "Read Data" method.

What I also have is a Manager class, in which I have placed a private instance of the Database class.  In this Manager class, I have also included a "Read Data from Database" and "Send Data to Database" method. All these do is accept the required parameters and use them to run the Database's Read/Write methods.

Other than a few misc methods whose code could easily be run from elsewhere, Manager's only purpose's to act as a messenger between the program and the Database class to prevent Database from needing to be instantiated directly in the form.

Am I on the right track here or am I just creating more work for myself by not simply creating a Database object in the form and running everything directly from there?

Comment: I believe you are not understanding the concept of proxy classes. All classes may have private data.

Comment: Forget about 'proxy classes' for now.

It sounds like you are talking about a layer of abstraction over your database layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with John Saunders on this - you're using the class in some realm of "correctness", but not for a real purpose.

As described in your example, a proxy class is used as an abstraction.  Your executing code doesn't need to know anything about the data source - it just submits a request for data and gets data back as a response.  The proxy hides this implementation detail from you - it could retrieve the data from a flat file, a database, a web service; it really doesn't matter.  This makes your code more flexible because it's not tied to a specific database implementation, and it also makes it testable because you can inject some other class in there that provides test ("mock") data.